# Can I append value to a output text file along with string?

Tags: python

Can I append a value to an output text file along with string in python

```
out=open('output.txt','a')
count=5
out.write(count)
```

Can I put the dynamic value as an argument for `out.write()`

error: `out.write(count)`:

> TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object

Comment: If you're asking if write is able to accept variables to write into files, the answer is yes. In your example above, it should work if you coerce it into a string object. `out.write(str(count))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either make `count` a string value from the start:

```
count = "5"
```

Or transform it into a string as you're writing it:

```
out.write('%d' % count)
```